# How can "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit" happen?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing

I just got an edit rejected during review, with the reason:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Looking at the subsequent conflicting review, it's not that different from mine.

I am just wondering how can this be? I have encountered situations where I cannot edit because another edit is underway, or when the question is changed during my revision.

In general, how are the revisions prioritized? Is it based on time (in which case this rejection reason makes no sense), or  reputation, or number of words changed, or some other status/criteria?

Also, this rejection is by "community". Does that mean this is from an automatic mechanism and not a human judgement? Is there a way to avoid spending time on such rejected edits?

Comment: See if the following post answers your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits. If it does not, please explain why. Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva Thanks. It seems to be the edge (concurrent) case where a user with full editing privileges trumped my edit after I submitted it.

Comment: If you can include a link to a post where you saw this happen then I may be able to use mod tools to look at its history and try to explain why.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks. Here is the link http://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/99823

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Meta Q&A ([Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)) suggested by @AndreSilva it looks like this may apply:

> If a user with full editing privileges for a post (including the
>   original poster) begins editing the post at the same time as you, and
>   they save their edit after you have already suggested it, then your
>   suggested edit will be overridden in favor of their fully-privileged
>   edit.

It looks like you (with less than 2,000 rep) proposed your edit at 14:50:37 and the other user (with nearly 3,000 rep) completed their edit at 14:51:02.  I am guessing but cannot be certain that you both started editing at about the same time and each received optimistic locks on that question.  Consequently, I think the behaviour that you observed is as per the documentation.

I found the precise times by hovering over text like "8 hours ago" at the bottom of posts/versions.  I think any user can do the same to see these but it is also possible that it was a mod privilege that enabled me to.